# DocusignApi - Name & title entered by signer during signing?

Tags: docusignapi, signing

Is there a capability in Docusign that allows users to enter text (name, title, etc.) while Signing the document?

Example workflow:

1. User receives signing link
2. User uses link to go to the Docusign signing page
3. User should be able to enter their name & title, and sign the document

Can you plz point me to the documentation if such a feature is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for is the TextTabs functionality. That fit my requirements perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The only easy way that I know to do this, is by using PowerForms.
When you send a link to PowerForm, it's not a signing link like in your #1, it's a link that anyone can use to fill in their information and start a signing session.
The other option, is to use a little known feature of remote signing where the user gets an email, but that URL goes to your server first, you then use your app code to collect information you want, make API calls to update the envelope and use embedded signing to allow them to complete the process.
The latter is a more complex option, requires more code and your own server etc. but it would prevent the issue of the link being exposes to anyone.